# Heroku node.js app not compatible with buildpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, discord

I tried uploading my discord bot to heroku today, but everytime I use `git push heroku master` it will give me the following error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-
buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tg
remote:        More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to sjak-bot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/sjak-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sjak-bot.git'
```

I already did `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`, added the node.js and npm version to the package.json, but it still gives the same error.

The bot is written in javascript btw

Comment: Have you created the Procfile?

Comment: And is your `package.json` file in the root of your repository?

Comment: Yes I have a Procfile, this is the code inside of it: `web: node index.js`, and yes, the package.json is in the root of the repository.

Comment: Did you have any success? I am getting the same messages and can't find this error anywhere on the heroku docs or the web.

Comment: I forgot to create `package.json`, so I typed `npm init` and created one and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `index.js` file to your main directory, in my case I just added `index.php` file